# Ruby: Strange behaviour when defining methods that utilize syntax sugar

Tags: ruby, syntax, metaprogramming

Currently I'm playing around with the a few meta-programming ideas, let me introduce that first:
I can define a string 'template' in a `class` or `module` as a `Constant` and utilize it later like so:

```
class Test1
  ConstString = %(the string in here is %{instring})
end
puts Test1::ConstString % { instring: "test" }
#=> the string in here is test
```

The problem is

a. based on a benchmark, just defining a function could do the same thing 3 times as fast (Benchmark is 1000000.times):

```
                 user     system      total        real
   Constant:   1.080000   0.000000   1.080000 (  1.087187)
   Function:   0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  0.346578)
```

b. I want to keep these separated from regular functions because of how I want to use them.

So I decided to create a new class to inherit from Proc...
And include a `module` to throw in Percent/Modulo Syntax.

```
module ProcPercentSyntax
  def %(*args)
    self.call(*args)
  end
end
class TestFromProc < Proc
  include ProcPercentSyntax
end


class Test2
  ConstString = TestFromProc.new { |x, y| %(this is a string with #{x} and #{y}) }
end
```

That way, I can call it like so!

```
puts Test2::ConstString % "test", "test2"
```

But...

```
#=> this is a string with test and
```

Disconcertingly without any error thrown.

To make sure this wasn't another issue I went ahead and did this:

```
module ProcNotPercentSyntax
  def make(*args)
    self.call(*args)
  end
end
```

---

```
class TestFromProc < Proc
  include ProcNotPercentSyntax
end
```

---

```
puts Test2::ConstString.make "test", "test2"
```

And...

```
#=> this is a string with test and test2
```

Excuse the drawling sporadic nature of this question, I'll summarize my intent as so:

> Why does the method seem to miss out on the second given parameter when using `%` as a method name?

Comment: Don't you need the parentheses in an ambiguous situation like this?

Comment: Try to change your code to make it working this way: `puts Test2::ConstString % ["test", "test2"]`. Maybe String's `%` method just takes one argument.

Comment: It does work with the `[]` explicitly passed, however I want to know why the `.make` example accepts the implicit `"string", "string"` and ` % ` Doesn't, and if there's a way of making it accept implicit.

Comment: What gives `p args` in ProcPercentSyntax's `%` method?

Comment: `#=> "test"` It appears that `Test2::ConstString % "test", "test2"` is being interpreted as `[Test2::ConstString.%("test"), "test2"]` here, in which case I'll likely have to settle for your Array Syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> puts Test2::ConstString % "test", "test2"
> ```
>
> But...
>
> ```
> #=> this is a string with test and
> ```

No, that is *not* the result. The result is:

```
# this is a string with test and 
# test2
#=> nil
```

> Disconcertingly without any error thrown.

Why would there be an error? It is perfectly legal to call `puts` with two arguments, and that is what you are doing here. What would you expect

```
puts 1+1, 3
```

to print? It's the exact same thing!

> Why does the method seem to miss out on the second given parameter when using `%` as a method name?

`%` is a *binary* operator like `<<` or `|`. It only takes *two* operands, one on the left (the receiver of the message) and one on the right. There is only one ternary operator in Ruby (`?:`) but a) that doesn't take two operands on the right, it takes its three operands with the operator interleaved (like this `a ? b : c`) and b) it cannot be overloaded.

Note that this has nothing to do with the name `%`, it has to do with operator syntax:

```
puts Test2::ConstString.% "test", "test2"
# this is a string with test and test2
#=> nil
```

Comment: I had a lot of `puts` in my method and neglected to notice the additional line being outputted via the test `puts` on my Object.  Your Answer gave me the insight I needed to finish off the code, thank you!